# C# args.Cancel = true; not stopping my worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application which controls some industrial processes.  Some of these processes are time-consuming so the application creates a worker thread to run them.  The thread is set to be cancellable and to report progress.

```
    CertifyBWThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    // this allows the worker to report progress during work
    CertifyBWThread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

A button is supplied to cancel the thread before it would normally finish.

```
if (CertifyBWThread != null)
{
    CertifyBWThread.CancelAsync();
}
```

As the thread runs it periodically checks to see if a cancellation has been scheduled.  args is **DoWorkEventArgs** .

```
//check for cancellation here
if (CertifyBWThread.CancellationPending)
{
    args.Cancel = true;                
}
```

... I routinely hit this code in the debugger.   Once I've called CancelAsync() it hits this every time through a loop that controls the industrial process and sets args.Cancel to true.    But still merrily the thread runs.    What is supposed to happen when args.Cancel is set to true?

Comment: The worker thread needs to check the `CancellationPending` to determine if it should stop and exit or not.

Comment: @Ron Beyer Don't I show that in the code?

Comment: Is there a `return` missing from that code?  Yes.

Comment: @usr it is posted - don't you see the code where the comment says "//check for cancellation pending here".   And as I said, in the debugger it does execute the line where it sets cancel to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `DoWork()` handler checks `CancellationPending`, it is not sufficient to simply set `DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel` to `true`. Your `DoWork` handler must *also* stop working.

Setting `DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel` to `true` is important, because that's how the `BackgroundWorker` object itself will be able to tell the difference between your `DoWork` handler returning having cancelled the operation and returning having actually *completed* the operation. This addresses the possible race condition between code trying to cancel the operation and the operation itself (i.e. this way the code trying to cancel the operation can determine whether the operation was in fact cancelled, or if it completed successfully before it had a chance to check on the cancellation).

But it's up to *you* to write your `DoWork` event handler such that it will in fact interrupt its operation when the `CancellationPending` property gets set to `true`.

I've based this answer on inferences from the incomplete code example in your question. If the above does not address your concern, then please improve your question so that it includes [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.